# MySql query same table to gather to-date and year-to-date information

Tags: sql, mysql

I've been struggling with this problem for hours, even though I'm sure there is an easy answer.  I'm attempting to gather monthly information and year-to-date information from the same table. I'm also joining a second table to gather the group name.

expense Table:

```
+-----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | int(5)        | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| account         | char(14)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| batch           | int(5)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| date            | date          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| description     | varchar(50)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| debit           | decimal(10,2) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| credit          | decimal(10,2) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| account_data_id | varchar(14)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

account_data table:

```
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(5)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| account_code | varchar(14) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| group_name   | varchar(30) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I can easily come up with either monthly or year-to-date information, but no matter what I do I'm not able to have both. Below is the closest I can come up with, but it takes forever to execute and the results are not whats expected:

```
SELECT account_data.group_name, sum(m.debit)- sum(m.credit) AS month, sum(y.debit)- SUM(y.credit) AS year
FROM account_data
INNER JOIN expense m ON m.account_data_id = account_data.id
AND MONTH(m.`date`) IN (7,8,9,10,11,12)
LEFT JOIN expense y ON y.account_data_id = account_data.id
AND MONTH(y.`date`) IN (7)
GROUP BY account_data.group_name
```

This is what I'm looking to accomplish:

```
+--------------+----------+---------+
| group_name   | month    | year    | 
+--------------+----------+---------+
| Payroll      | 10,000   | 50,000  |
| Payroll Tax  | 1,000    | 5,000   |
| Benefits     | 500      | 1,000   |  
+--------------+----------+---------+
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.  I'm new here and I hope I've followed all rules and have provided any of you with enough information to help, but if not let me know and I will provide more.

@philwinkle -Your solution, properly modified:

```
SELECT ad.group_name,
IF(MONTH(e.date) IN (7,8,9,10,11,12), SUM(e.debit) - SUM(e.credit),'' ),
IF(MONTH(e.date) = 7, SUM(e.debit) - SUM(e.credit),'' )
FROM account_data ad
LEFT JOIN expense_2011 e ON e.account_data_id = ad.id
WHERE e.account_data_id > 7
GROUP BY ad.group_name
```

Comment: do you want each month:  group_name, jan, feb, mar, total?

Comment: Why do you need them both done in the same query? Can't you just run two queries, then join the data together in post-processing?

Comment: @Nathan - I don't need each month.  Just one month and YTD.   @CanSpice - a post-processing script is not an option, otherwise the solution would have been easy to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

The solution here is to use conditional sums... I'm going to put pseudo-code and I'll edit when I'm 100% positive the below solution validates and works:

```
SELECT ad.group_name,
(if(e.account_data_id IN (7,8,9,10,11,12),sum(e.debit)- sum(e.credit)) AS month,
(if(e.account_data_id=7,sum(e.debit)- sum(e.credit)) AS year
FROM account_data ad
LEFT JOIN expense e ON e.account_data_id = ad.id
WHERE e.account_data_id > 7
GROUP BY account_data.group_name
```

Comment: Also, add an index to account_data_id and it should help improve the speed of that join

Comment: Also - `IN()` is a pretty expensive operation... is there another way to identify those account types?

Comment: IN actually references the month(s) of the date and not the account type. And I haven't been able to come up with a better solution than IN. Perhaps with more conditions placed on the month I could.

Comment: @philwinkle - I've adjusted your code to properly reflect the reference to the date, instead of the account_data_id and tested it.  The month and year sum up to the same value, if the value exists in 7.  I'm loving your approach so far though.

Comment: @user621928: So you're saying that account_data_id is the month part of a datetime?

Comment: @philwinkle - I've edited your code and included in the original post so that you can see how it should be structured. account_data essentially contains the name by which the expense should be grouped (payroll, payroll taxes, and so on). This way each expense has a group name.  So if you filter by account_data_id you will be filtering out group names. I need the filter to be on months. 7 representing July (beginning of fiscal year) and so on, while 7,8,9,10,11,12 representing YTD (July - Dec). Did I explain well enough?